# Issue with scaffold asp.net razor pages using an entity framework core dbcontext inside a separate class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, class-library

I am using `Ubuntu LTS 18.4 LTS` operating system. I created an `asp.net core 3.0` razor pages project and a class library from terminal using cli.

I have an existing mariadb database, so i used database first approach. I scaffolded my entity type classes and a `DbContext` class into a class library, based on an existing database schema.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;Port=3306;User ID=root;Password=secure_password;Database=Food;Pooling=true;" "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" --startup-project ../FoodV2.UI/ -c FoodDbContext --output-dir Models
```

DAL csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.2.6" />    
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

DBContext:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace FoodV2.Dal.Models
{
    public partial class FoodDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public FoodDbContext()
        {
        }

        public FoodDbContext(DbContextOptions<FoodDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<TblFood> TblFood { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TblFoodType> TblFoodType { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TblHealthBenefit> TblHealthBenefit { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TblIllness> TblIllness { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TblNutrients> TblNutrients { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TblNutrientsType> TblNutrientsType { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TblSideEffect> TblSideEffect { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TblUnitOfMeasurement> TblUnitOfMeasurement { get; set; }

        // Unable to generate entity type for table 'tblFood2Nutrients'. Please see the warning messages.
        // Unable to generate entity type for table 'tblFoodHealthBenefit'. Please see the warning messages.
        // Unable to generate entity type for table 'tblFoodSideEffect'. Please see the warning messages.
        // Unable to generate entity type for table 'tblFoodToCure'. Please see the warning messages.
        // Unable to generate entity type for table 'tblNutrientsHealthBenefit'. Please see the warning messages.
        // Unable to generate entity type for table 'tblNutrientsSideEffect'. Please see the warning messages.
        // Unable to generate entity type for table 'tblNutrientsToCure'. Please see the warning messages.

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {

            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TblFood>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("tblFood");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.FoodTypeId)
                    .HasName("tblFood_FK");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("ID")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'current_timestamp()'")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

                entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasColumnType("varchar(300)");

                entity.Property(e => e.FoodTypeId)
                    .HasColumnName("FoodTypeID")
                    .HasColumnType("smallint(6)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl).HasColumnType("varchar(500)");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'b\\'1\\''");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("timestamp");

                entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(100)");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.FoodType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.TblFood)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FoodTypeId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("tblFood_FK");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblFoodType>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("tblFoodType");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("ID")
                    .HasColumnType("smallint(6)");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'current_timestamp()'")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

                entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasColumnType("varchar(300)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl).HasColumnType("varchar(150)");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'b\\'1\\''");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("timestamp");

                entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblHealthBenefit>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("tblHealthBenefit");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("ID")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'current_timestamp()'")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

                entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl).HasColumnType("varchar(150)");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'b\\'1\\''");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("timestamp");

                entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(150)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblIllness>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("tblIllness");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("ID")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'current_timestamp()'")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

                entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl).HasColumnType("varchar(150)");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'b\\'1\\''");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("timestamp");

                entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(150)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblNutrients>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("tblNutrients");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.NutrientsTypeId)
                    .HasName("tblNutrients_FK");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("ID")
                    .HasColumnType("smallint(6)");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'current_timestamp()'")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

                entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasColumnType("varchar(300)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl).HasColumnType("varchar(150)");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'b\\'1\\''");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("timestamp");

                entity.Property(e => e.NutrientsTypeId)
                    .HasColumnName("NutrientsTypeID")
                    .HasColumnType("smallint(6)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.NutrientsType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.TblNutrients)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.NutrientsTypeId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("tblNutrients_FK");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblNutrientsType>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("tblNutrientsType");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("ID")
                    .HasColumnType("smallint(6)");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'current_timestamp()'")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

                entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasColumnType("varchar(300)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl).HasColumnType("varchar(150)");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'b\\'1\\''");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("timestamp");

                entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblSideEffect>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("tblSideEffect");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("ID")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'current_timestamp()'")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

                entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl).HasColumnType("varchar(150)");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'b\\'1\\''");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("timestamp");

                entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(150)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblUnitOfMeasurement>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("tblUnitOfMeasurement");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("ID")
                    .HasColumnType("tinyint(4)");

                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
                    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'current_timestamp()'")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

                entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(500)");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("bit(1)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'b\\'1\\''");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedOn).HasColumnType("timestamp");

                entity.Property(e => e.Symbol)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(10)");

                entity.Property(e => e.SystemOfMeasurement)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Tag)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(100)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Unit)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FoodV2.Dal.Models
{
    public partial class TblUnitOfMeasurement
    {
        public sbyte Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string SystemOfMeasurement { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UI csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FoodV2.Dal\FoodV2.Dal.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.2.6" />       
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Also, I did the required wiring between UI and DAL project.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDbContext<Dal.Models.FoodDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MariadbConnection")));
        }
```

At last, I tried to scaffold razor pages on UI project using the `Dbcontext` in class library project. When I tried to run the below command, it throws the error:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m TblUnitOfMeasurement -dc ../FoodV2.Dal.Models.FoodDbContext -udl -outDir Areas/Admin/Pages/UnitOfMeasurement -namespace FoodV2.UI.Areas.Admin.Pages.UnitOfMeasurement -scripts
```

command output on terminal:

```
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
Running the generator 'razorpage'...
Sequence contains more than one matching element
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowMoreThanOneMatchException()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:11.87
```

Comment: Don't post the code screenshots, post the actual code so that people can see and help.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the MySql query provider. You better post the exception there.